# analysis of different time series

Tags: time-series, data-preprocessing

i have 26000 items of a shop (rows) and the sell quantity in every week of 2017( 52 columns). i'm doing forecasting: this is the goal. 
Now, however i'm in the data preprocessing step and i want understand the noise and calculate some correlation analysis (analysis of time series).

I want do for example a cluster of items that bought in the winter and in the summer and continuo's items and then apply mixture regression or glm .

However, now my problem is to do analysis for all the time series of all items. I have no idea of how i can have the correlation analysis of all the items in a easy way.

The idea, very hard, that i have is to do a function that do all type of analysis and do a cicle for all items and save the results in different matrix.

Have anyone any idea?

Comment: First of all unless you have data over several years, it will be hard to assess seasonality for the week of the year. You say forecasting is your goal, but it is unclear what exactly you want to forecast. The amount of products sold in the next week? Or a year from now? Or do you want a distribution or confidence interval of these products? As you can see there are multiple possibilties so you will have to be more specific. Clustering the items in winter and summer would be good. I would add a dummy variable that indicates whether a product belongs to a certain season or special event.

Comment: Yes.i'm sorry. i want do forecasting about amount of products sold in the next two week . i use a variable that indicates in the cluster if item continuos ( sell every mouth) , or the season. My question is about the data preprocessing. Is it wrong consider data in the cluster without analysis of correlation and other time series analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You might develop an arima model and include intervention detection procedures to identify pulses for each individual series unusual values . Then classify them according to the dates of the unusual values yielding common structure. If you wished to post a small example of say 10 series , I might be able to help further.

Comment: how i can send data now here?

Comment: you can email it to me at dave@autobox.com as I don'r precisely know how to attach a csv file or a zip file to a SE post.

Comment: You can post the data to dropbox and share the link here